# Deleting a PFFile from Parse via iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, rest, parse-platform

I'm trying to allow users to delete a profile image they previously uploaded. I understand that Parse's SDK does not permit deletion of PFFiles, so I must use the REST API correct? I think perhaps my URL is invalid. Am I supposed to use the name of the file as seen in Parse? In my case, profile images are uploaded as "profilePic-(user's objectId).jpg"

Here is my code:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.parse.com/1/files/profilePic-\(currentuser.objectId).jpg")!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "DELETE"
            request.setValue(appId, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
            request.setValue(clientKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Master-Key")
            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                println(response)
            }).resume()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.parse.com/1/files/profilePic-\(currentuser.objectId).jpg")!)

request.HTTPMethod = "DELETE"
request.setValue(appId, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Application-Id")
request.setValue(clientKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Parse-Master-Key")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    print("Response: \(response)")
})
task!.resume()
```

More information about the command (including security concerns) can be found in [Parse's official documentation](https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-delete-a-file).

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I may have done something wrong when implementing. The one thing I changed was I swapped out "urlSession" for "NSURLSession.sharedSession()" because it wouldn't compile otherwise.

Comment: yeah, typo on my part when I copied some of my code :-)

Comment: Note that the name of the file must be the name in the response of the upload operation, rather than the original filename, if someone knows any other alias please share with us